# ECS deployment timeout

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy my ecs but I faced a timeout issue

[image]

and my deployment get stuck here. How does this happen?

[image]

Comment: have you tried to stop the active task?

Comment: how do I do that? Deregister the task?

Comment: Ok it works. But then do I have to stop the task every time i deploy new code into the code pipeline?

Comment: In my case, i am using Jenkins, so i just create bash script to run aws cli stop task. In yours, i think you can use lambda

Comment: You mean write it to buildspec.yml to use lambda? I uses codebuild and codedeploy in code pipeline

Comment: well if you use codebuild you can run aws cli directly on buildspec.yml to stop the task after deployment

Comment: I realise that the taskArns always changes when you deploy. How do you pick it up using bash and append it to ecs stop-task command?

Comment: i put on the answer section, please check and try,
you have to aws configure first tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my step to get the taskArn using aws cli

```
cluster="clustername"
service_arn=$( aws ecs list-services --cluster $cluster --query 'serviceArns[0]' --output text )
task_arn=$( aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $cluster --service-name $service_arn --query 'taskArns[0]' --output text )
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I should not set the minimum healthy percentage to 50%. I should set it to 0% so as to allow the task to change

Comment: If your system is allowed to have a downtime is fibe tk set theit to 0%